# Python/Pandas aggregating by date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to count and plot the number of data points I have for each area by day, so far I have: 
[image]

But I would like to show the number of instances of each county per day, with the end goal of plotting them on a line graph, like:

[image]

Only I would want to plot each county on its own line, rather than the total which I have plotted above.

Update:

I have managed to get this from the answers provided:

[image]

Which is great and exactly what I was looking for. However, in hindsight, this looks a little messy and not very descriptive even for the short period plotted let alone if I were to plot this for a couple of years worth of data.

So I'm thinking to plot this indivually on an 8 grid plot. But when I try to plot this for one county I am getting the boolean values. As below:

[image]

What would be the best way to plot only the True values?

Comment: df[df.county == 'Surrey'].groupby(df.date_stamp).count() --selection in groupby causes the boolean results. If you're interested in one particular county then why are you grouping by county --you shouldn't do that. Instead select first then group by only by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
df.county.groupby([df.date_stamp, df.county]).count().unstack().plot();
```

- `df.county...count()` is the numerical series you want to plot.
- `groupby([df.date_stamp, df.county])` groups first by `date_stamp`, then by `country` (the order matters).
- `unstack` will create a Dataframe whose index is the time stamp, and columns are counties.
- `plot();` will plot it (and the `;` suppresses the unnecessary output).

**Edit**

To plot it on separate plots, you could do something like

```
for county in df.county.unique():
    this_county = df[df.county == county]
    this_county.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).count().plot();
    title(county);
    show();
```

Comment: Just made an update on the question - would greatly appreciate your opinion!

Comment: Thanks again!! @Ami Tavory

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.crosstab(df['date_stamp'],df['county']).plot()
```

EDIT: question changed, if you want them in subplots instead of lines:

```
pd.crosstab(df['date_stamp'],df['county']).plot(subplots=True)
```

The key in drawing each county as a separate line is that each county needs to be in a different column. If you just want to count them, crosstab is then probably the shortest way to achieve that result. For example:

[image]

Then the result is:
[image: pd.crosstab(df['date_stamp'],df['county']).plot()]

When `subplots=True`:

[image: pd.crosstab(df['date_stamp'],df['county']).plot(subplots=True)]

Comment: Just made an update on the question - would greatly appreciate your opinion!